# What's the difference of intern() between JDK 1.6 and JDK 1.7?

Tags: java

Java code

```
String s1 = new StringBuilder("computer ").append("software").toString();
System.out.println(s1.intern() == s1);
String s2 = new StringBuilder("ja").append("va").toString();
System.out.println(s2.intern() == s2);
```

In JDK 1.6,the result is

```
false
false
```

but int JDK 1.7,

```
true
false
```

Could you please tell me the reasons?

Comment: It's probably just that "java" was not in the intern pool in 6, but was in 7 for done reason. Could be almost anything; it's probably just some private static field that one of the basic classes has.

Comment: I was going to google this for you when I thought, "Why would I do this for them? They obviously have Internet access. Surely they could look it up, right? Perhaps they haven't heard of Google?" Anyway, sorry, I changed my mind.